# InfluxDB database suddenly just stops

Tags: raspbian, grafana, influxdb

I had a couple of power outages today due to some electrical work being done on my house. Now I'm finding that my InfluxDB / Grafana set up not working for very long before crashing - I think that it is InfluxDB that is crashing.

I collect air quality measures from about 60 Luftdaten sensors every 165 seconds. I also use Grafana to make dashboards. Both the Grafana and the InfluxDB running on same Raspberry Pi 3B. Was running great for a quite a while (like 40 days?) before now.

InfluxDB 1.7.3
Grafana 5.1.4

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ df -h     
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
/dev/root        30G  5.6G   23G  20% /  
devtmpfs        460M     0  460M   0% /dev  
tmpfs           464M     0  464M   0% /dev/shm  
tmpfs           464M   47M  417M  11% /run  
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock  
tmpfs           464M     0  464M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup  
/dev/mmcblk0p1   44M   23M   22M  51% /boot  
tmpfs            93M     0   93M   0% /run/user/1000
```